# Patching a Compiled OS X Framework

Tags: macos, qt, frameworks

So I have a relatively old application with a bug in it that I wanted to fix. The bug was something wrong with Qt, and it was packaged as a .framework so I downloaded the Qt source, patched the bug and recompiled the frameworks. The problem was that this introduced a bug because it would appear that they had modified the source in some other area.

I dont have a lot of experience with this thing, so I came here for a bit of advice. Is it possible to do this? I did some digging and noticed that there were some decompilers (such as otool) but that this uses assembly. I've never really looked at assembly (I don't mind learning if this would work) but it looked to me like there were a lot of pointers that I'm afraid would be broken if I tried to inject my own code.

If anyone knows if this is possible / a direction to move in, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.